# How to return a LINQ Anonymoustype to a typed collection

Tags: c#, linq

I am having below LINQ which I want to return into a collectionList.

```
var StudIds = from _NewIds in NewIds.AsEnumerable()
           join _OldIds in allOldIds.AsEnumerable()
           on _NewIds.Field<int>("Id") equals _OldIds.Field<int>("Id")
           where _NewIds.Field<Boolean>("IsExist") == true && _NewIds.Field<string>("FieldName") == "FinalValue"
           select new
           {
               Id = _NewIds.Field<int>("Id"),
               Name = _NewIds.Field<string>("Name"),
               Value = _NewIds.Field<decimal>("PRice")
           };



List<std> lstCustomWebsiteVerifiedIndex = new List<std>();
```

This Std class is haivg Id, name and Value as datamember.

Any idea how to typecast this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of projecting it to an anonymous class in the first place you should use `std` class like:

```
  select new std
      {
          Id = _NewIds.Field<int>("Id"),
          Name = _NewIds.Field<string>("Name"),
          Value = _NewIds.Field<decimal>("PRice")
      };
```

and later you can do:

```
List<std> lstCustomWebsiteVerifiedIndex  = StudIds.ToList();
```

But if your class `std` is generated through some framework (like Entity framework) then you will not be able to use projection, in that case you will need a temporary class.

Also if you can't modify existing code *(with anonymous class)* then you can use your query to project to your list like:

```
List<std> lstCustomWebsiteVerifiedIndex = StudIds.Select(r=> new std
                                            {
                                              Id = r.Id, 
                                              Name = r.Name, 
                                              Value = r.Value,
                                            })
                                           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use an anonymous type, just project directly to your `std` type:

```
var StudIds = from _NewIds in NewIds.AsEnumerable()
              join _OldIds in allOldIds.AsEnumerable()
              on _NewIds.Field<int>("Id") equals _OldIds.Field<int>("Id")
              where _NewIds.Field<Boolean>("IsExist") == true && _NewIds.Field<string>("FieldName") == "FinalValue"
              select new std
              {
                  Id = _NewIds.Field<int>("Id"),
                  Name = _NewIds.Field<string>("Name"),
                  Value = _NewIds.Field<decimal>("PRice")
              };
```